# Rails Routes Redirect To Blog On Subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have moved a blog from my main domain to a sub domain and want to redirect traffic that was directed at the original blog to the same post on the subdomain using Rails 5.1 routes and wildcards.

For example, my original address was https://www.dolgins.com/blog/2018/5/22/unique-hand-crafted-mosaic-jewelry-at-richard-dolgin-private-jeweler. Now, if someone enters this address, he/she would be redirected to https://blog.dolgins.com/blog/2018/5/22/unique-hand-crafted-mosaic-jewelry-at-richard-dolgin-private-jeweler.

Here is my current routes that pertain:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'blog/*all' => redirect(subdomain: 'blog', path: '%{all}')
  get "/blog" => redirect("https://blog.dolgins.com")
end
```

However, these routes redirect to http://blog.dolgins.com/2018/5/22/unique-hand-crafted-mosaic-jewelry-at-richard-dolgin-private-jeweler versus http://blog.dolgins.com**/blog**/2018/5/22/unique-hand-crafted-mosaic-jewelry-at-richard-dolgin-private-jeweler with the bold showing the difference.

Any ideas about what my routes should be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'blog/*all' => redirect(subdomain: 'blog', path: '/blog/%{all}')
  get "/blog" => redirect("https://blog.dolgins.com")
end
```

Comment: I thought to try that, and when I do that Rails apprends a second blog in the subdomain as well. The resulting URL is http://blog.blog.dolgins.com/blog/2018/5/22/unique-hand-crafted-mosaic-jewelry-at-richard-dolgin-private-jeweler. Any thoughts? Thank you for your response.

Comment: sorry, I think I missed a `/` at `'/blog/%{all}'`

Comment: Actually. It was not working in development but works in production. Not sure why in development it adds that second "blog" but it works! Thank you!